# Prove $\tan(\sin^{-1}t)=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is there anyway that can prove $-\tan(\sin^{-1}(t))=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ ?

I was able to prove $\tan(\sin^{-1}(-t))=-\tan(\sin^{-1}(t))$ but don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: It depends on your definitions of $\sin^{-1}$ and $\sqrt{\cdot}$, but for the definitions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Properties_and_uses), arguably the most common in use, the value of $-\tan(\sin^{-1}(1/2))$ would be negative, while the right-hand side is positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sin\theta = t$, with $\theta\in [-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$ the range of $\sin^{-1}t$. Then,

$$\cos \theta= \sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta} = \sqrt{1-t^2}$$

Thus,

$$\tan ( \sin^{-1}t)=\tan\theta= \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac t{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sin^{-1}(t)=\phi$. By definition of the arc sine, we have $\phi\in[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$. Then the equation reads

$$\tan(\phi)=\frac{\sin(\phi)}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\phi)}}=\frac{\sin(\phi)}{\cos(\phi)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Refer to the right-triangle diagram above.

Answer (score 0):

First use the definition: $\tan(x) = \sin(x)/ \cos(x)$.

Then simply use the Pythagorean theorem: $\sin(x)^2 + \cos(x)^2 = 1 $
from which we follow $\cos(x) = \sqrt{1 -\sin(x)^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Draw a right triangle. With respect to angle referred,

Opposite side $=t$, hypotenuse$=1$, adjacent side $= \sqrt{1-t^2}$

Now how is $\tan$ defined?